# Update user meta when an external link in admin notice is clicked

Tags: php, plugin-development

I want my plugin to show a dismissable notice. There are 2 links that do not redirect the user anywhere, just dismiss the notice and make sure that it will never show up again. This is only a minimal example from my settings class and this part works flawlessly:

I have the following in construct:

```
add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'acau_notice' ) );
add_action('admin_init', array( $this, 'acau_ignore_notice') );
```

The following is a part of `acau_notice` function:

```
global $current_user ;
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

if ( ! get_user_meta( $user_id, 'acau_ignore_notice' )) {       
        echo '<p><a href="?acau_ignore_notice=0">Dismiss permanently 1</a></p>';
        echo '<p><a href="?acau_ignore_notice=0">Dismiss permanently 2</a></p>';
    }
}
```

And here is a function to store the information whether the notice should be displayed:

```
public function acau_ignore_notice() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    if ( isset($_GET['acau_ignore_notice']) && '0' == $_GET['acau_ignore_notice'] ) {
        add_user_meta($user_id, 'acau_ignore_notice', 'true', true);
    }
}
```

I would like to `echo` a third link that redirects the user to an external page, but also make it dismiss the notice and make it never show up again. Can it be done with PHP?

Comment: Why does both the links point to the exact same URL (`?acau_ignore_notice=0`)? And for the third link, you could use a custom parameter such as `r` (for "redirect") as in `?acau_ignore_notice=0&r=1`. And in `acau_ignore_notice()`, you can do something like `if ( ! empty( $_GET['r'] ) ) { wp_redirect( 'URL' ); exit; }`

Comment: Many thanks, unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work. The redirect took place, but the notice would not be dismissed. In the end, I did this automation through Ajax, it came out to be much simpler than I thought. The 2 links now have `href="#"` and the other one a link to the external page. I use `$(document).on( 'click', '#acau_notice_container a', function() {` to trigger Ajax action that is a function to `update_option` and I hide the notice container on response. Yes, I no longer use user_meta, I realized that it could be spammy for larger websites with multiple admin users.

Comment: About your earlier question - why 2 links with the same URL - I have 2 different clickable answers that both provide a reason not to display the notice again without any action. The third option is going to an external link and I wanted not to display the notice once it's clicked, what I've achieved. With the previous solution, there was also a problem with adding a query string to the existing query string in url.

Comment: Actually, [this](https://gist.github.com/5ally/e2601015f7c6a13fa0b91f8812c154f3) is what I meant and it worked for me. But if the name `r` doesn't work, then you can use `redirect` or something like that. That gist is just for reference, though.